# Sharepoint view customization

Tags: sharepoint, view, field, caml

I'd like to complete redo the annoucements, and i'm having issues getting the CAML to do what i want. I want to grab each Field( i assume this is what i want to grab) and style them.
Say  i want the Title to be in bold red and the body in green

How would I accomplish this using CAML? I am customizing the View Style,  adding my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions to the CAML, so you can return a different block of code for fields with different name, if that's what you want. I think it's easier to do that with XSLT dataviews if we are talking about an isolated issue